# Tkinter SQlite - Search Function not working

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Good evening,

This is a simple function reading the value of an entry widget and searching in the database for it. It won´t run.
Could someone kindly point me to my rookie mistake?

This is the Function:

```
def find_search_term(self, search_term):
    search_term = self.search_entry.get()
    conn=sqlite3.connect("KTRmini.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM KTRmini_table WHERE discription LIKE "%search_term%",")
    data=c.fetchone()[0]
    print(discription)
    conn.close()
```

This is the Error:

c.execute("SELECT * FROM KTRmini_table WHERE discription LIKE "%search_term%",")
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Ask yourself what does python do when you try to put double quotes inside of double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM KTRmini_table WHERE discription LIKE %?%", search_term)
```

Comment: Hi user18190922,
thank you but that way I get a new error:

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM KTRmini_table WHERE discription LIKE %?%", search_term)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @Kinderdisco Why do you accept an incorrect answer?

Comment: acw1668 - you are right. My mistake. Sorry.
Even when the answer was incorrect it made me rethink the problem and solve ist myself.